# How to avoid that xtable flips the x and y axis of a table in the final output?

Tags: r, tex, xtable

I work with xtable which turns a table of r into a functionable latex code.

```
    <<echo=false>>=
attach(warpbreaks)
p2 <- round(tapply(breaks, list(tension), mean), digits=2) %>%
  as.table(.)
@
```

p2 looks like this:

```
  L     M     H 
36.39 26.39 21.67
```

But the output of the created pdf of this code:

```
<<echo=false, results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
xtable(p2,
       align = "rr")
@
```

looks (approximately) like this:

```
      x 
L 36.39 
M 26.39 
H 21.67
```

Why does it not look like the inital table in r and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you don't mind changing packages, you could do: `library(huxtable); t(as_hux(p2))`. And don't do `attach(warpbreaks)` ... very risky. :-)

Comment: Oh, and if you DO mind changing packages, you could just do `xtable(t(p2))`.